# Puzzling csh redirect behaviour

Tags: unix, csh

I found this very strange behaviour of csh while using output redirection.
I have the following script:

```
#! /bin/csh
set dirs = "."
set files = "`find "'"$dirs"'" -type f |& grep -v '^find: '`"
echo "-----------WITH &-----------------------"
echo "ARRAY:" $files
echo "FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1:" $files[1]

set files2 = "`find "'"$dirs"'" -type f`"
echo "------------WITHOUT &-----------------------"
echo "ARRAY2" $files2
echo "FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY" $files2[1]
```

Now if you run this, everything is OK. The results are:

```
-----------WITH &-----------------------
ARRAY: ./.netscape/preferences.js ...
FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: ./.netscape/preferences.js
------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
ARRAY2 ./.netscape/preferences.js ...
FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./.netscape/preferences.js
```

But when I run it like this csh -x test.csh (it's part of larger script so I have to debug it somehow) I get this:

```
set dirs = .
set files = `find "$dirs" -type f |& grep -v '^find: '`
grep -v ^find: 
echo -----------WITH &-----------------------
-----------WITH &-----------------------
echo ARRAY: find . -type f ./.netscape/preferences.js ...
ARRAY: find . -type f ./.netscape/preferences.js ...
echo FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: find . -type f
FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: find . -type f               <----WHY?
set files2 = `find "$dirs" -type f`
find . -type f
echo ------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
echo ARRAY2 ./.netscape/preferences.js ...
ARRAY2 ./.netscape/preferences.js ...
echo FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./.netscape/preferences.js
FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./.netscape/preferences.js
```

Now, when debugging this breaks the script. I find this behaviour quite puzzling. Can somebody explain why this happens and how to avoid it?

(Don't post useless comments that I shouldn't use csh, that it's rubbish. I know that. But my university kind of forces me to use it.)

EDIT: I did everything as suggested by John C. My output is different.

```
bash2-2.05a$ csh -x test.csh 2>catch_stderr
-----------WITH &-----------------------
ARRAY: find . -type f ./test.csh ./ff.csh ./ff ./catch_stderr
FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: find . -type f
------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
ARRAY2 ./test.csh ./ff.csh ./ff ./catch_stderr
FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./test.csh

bash2-2.05a$ cat catch_stderr 
set dirs = .
set files = `find "$dirs" -type f |& grep -v '^find: '`
grep -v ^find: 
echo -----------WITH &-----------------------
echo ARRAY: find . -type f ./test.csh ./ff.csh ./ff ./catch_stderr
echo FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: find . -type f
set files2 = `find "$dirs" -type f`
find . -type f
echo ------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
echo ARRAY2 ./test.csh ./ff.csh ./ff ./catch_stderr
echo FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./test.csh
```

Comment: Which university?  Are they actually forcing you to use it, or are they merely providing it as the default interactive shell?

Comment: Well they give us two options use CSH or some ancient version of BASH. But if you choose bash you are on your own because every example in lectures and practice sessions is explained in csh. I'd rather not name my university.

Comment: -x sends it's output to stderr.  I think you are just seeing stdout and stderr getting jumbled up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable -x applies for subshells also.

So when subshell `` `find "'"$dirs"'" -type f |& grep -v '^find: '` ``  gets executed it echoes `find . -type f` onto stderr (this is not captured by 2> not sure why, but it's not in my case) and then executes it, but the |& combines stderr and stdout and this combination gets substituted in the script. So the `find . -type f` ends up as the first element in array $files.

The solution is be very careful when using |& in ``` `` ``` csh is very tricky.

John C was right too. That actually pointed me in the right direction. So I upvoted his answer. His bash probably captures the output in subshell, so I think both outputs may occur. His output is certainly the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When you run csh -x it echoes each command to stderr.
If you turn on -x and run your script like this ....

```
>sh
sh-3.2$ csh -x test.csh 2>catch_stderr
-----------WITH &-----------------------
ARRAY: ./ff ./ff.csh ./test.csh
FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: ./ff
------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
ARRAY2 ./ff ./ff.csh ./test.csh
FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./ff

sh-3.2$ cat catch_stderr
set dirs = .
set files = `find "$dirs" -type f |& grep -v '^find: '`
find . -type f
grep -v ^find:
echo -----------WITH &-----------------------
echo ARRAY: ./ff ./ff.csh ./test.csh
echo FIRST ELEMENT FROM ARRAY1: ./ff
set files2 = `find "$dirs" -type f`
find . -type f
echo ------------WITHOUT &-----------------------
echo ARRAY2 ./ff ./ff.csh ./test.csh
echo FIRST ELEMENT SECOND ARRAY ./ff
```

(redirect stderr to a file) It will behave the same way as it did with no -x.
You can then look at the file `catch_stderr` to see the tracing info.
When they both come out together they can jumble each other up a bit.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong please. You are saying that if i run `csh -x script.csh 2>catch_stderr` it should give me the same output in catch_stderr as just running `csh script.csh` right? Because if I do that it still echoes the find as the first value in that array in catch_stderr.

Comment: Hmm looks like csh doesn't let you do stderr redirection.  Try starting a bash shell first then run your script as I explained and then you will see the effect I am trying to explain.   csh -x echoes each command before it is run.  When you have several commands in one line it echoes each individual command on a separate line.  This all gets mixed up with the regular stdout of the script.

Comment: I did try that, no luck same result. Let's assume that after both echos I'll add `echo head -n 1 < find . -type f ` (there is subshell quotes but markdown is interpreting it as code) In case that it is really only jumbled output of stdin and stderr I should see in both cases the first line of that file. But I still get `find: No such file or directory.`

Comment: I mean jumbled output of stdout and stderr sorry for the typo.

Comment: I did everything just like you. I edited my question and added the output.